# Fail2ban partial IP match possible?

Tags: ubuntu, fail2ban

My server (Ubuntu 18.04) is getting a lot of spam requests on Postfix. Fail2ban is working but the spammers keep changing the last part of IP and not getting banned. For example,

```
2021-10-09 09:40:01,260 fail2ban.filter         [790]: INFO    [postfix-sasl] Found 212.70.149.88 - 2021-10-09 09:40:01
2021-10-09 09:40:04,047 fail2ban.filter         [790]: INFO    [postfix-sasl] Found 31.130.184.201 - 2021-10-09 09:40:04
2021-10-09 09:40:08,697 fail2ban.filter         [790]: INFO    [postfix-sasl] Found 31.130.184.182 - 2021-10-09 09:40:08
2021-10-09 09:40:18,922 fail2ban.filter         [790]: INFO    [postfix-sasl] Found 31.130.184.119 - 2021-10-09 09:40:18
2021-10-09 09:40:21,627 fail2ban.filter         [790]: INFO    [postfix-sasl] Found 212.70.149.88 - 2021-10-09 09:40:21
```

Is there any option to make Fail2ban match the first 3 parts of an IP like match 31.130.184.0/24 and then block all the IPs above as soon as they're encountered?

Comment: subnet support will coming if i understood tge github.com repository of fail2ban

Comment: if you are sure you want to drop /24, why handling this via fail2ban. just go for iptables and drop /24. even less memory & cpu is used.

Comment: zareh i wanna see you 24/7 log monitoring with your explanations ;) i bet aftet 36 hours will be your physical end near

Comment: @djdomi either my English is bad, or i don't understand what you exactly mean!!!

Comment: also good to have @myname to get a notification on your update :)

Comment: @ZarehKasparian what he means and I concur, I do not intend to block this particular IP. It can be any IP sending malicious requests. I can not keep monitoring the logs and taking actions manually.

Comment: @ZarehKasparian whip understood what i meant ;) - he wants to avoid staying 24/7 awake to ban any  malicious request, and i meant latest after you being 36 hours awake, your physical end (falling a sleep) will be near ;)

Comment: @djdomi there is no need for someone to be awake. he/she can write a script to read the logs and get the IP address out of it and automatically block IP via iptables. that simple :)

Comment: Cool idea. Let's call it "Fail2Ban"!

Answer (score 2):

## Short Answer:

Fail2ban plans to support banning of Subnets in Version 1.0.

#### Reference

Bug Report:
https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/927

Mile-Stone Report:
https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/milestone/17

### Curent State:

Its not Official Supported, but could be added manually

Comment: I would like to add, that if you ban a subnet in the current state, fail2ban will not match that ban currently.