# Can fail2ban-client tell me if an ip from a CIDR range is in a jail?

Tags: fail2ban, cidr

If I have a CIDR like `13.54.63.128/26` can `fail2ban-client` tell me if there's an IP in this range that's currently banned?

Currently I'm doing:

```
CIDR="13.54.63.128/26"
nmap -sL -n $CIDR | awk '/Nmap scan report/{print $NF}' | while read ip
do
  sudo iptables -L -n | grep $ip
done
```

which does the job, but feels a bit hacky.

Please note this is *not* a question concerning fail2ban's partial IP matching. I want to know the client's ability to report on banned IPs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fail2ban partial IP match possible?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1080041/fail2ban-partial-ip-match-possible) - currently, fail2ban does not have Subnet support, its planned for the future

Comment: I feel the ability of `fail2ban-client` to tell if some IP from a given range is banned is *also* the ability of *fail2ban* (as a product) to do a partical IP matching. Not for adding a range into ban instead of single IP; the matching is going to be peformed for other use case, but the "duplicate" answer still fully applies.

Answer (score 3):

There is a nifty little tool [`grepcidr`](http://www.pc-tools.net/unix/grepcidr/) that is useful for quick shell scripts that need to find matches from a specific CIDR in a list with IPv4 or IPv6 addresses.

```
 sudo iptables -L -n | grepcidr  "13.54.63.128/26"
```